# Como traduzir plugins JS de forma dinâmica com Codeigniter?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, bower

Estou desenvolvendo um *WebApp* utilizando o Codeigniter e preciso que tenha vários idiomas, no PHP tranquilo, meu problema é como organizar as traduções dos plugins Javascript.

Exemplo, tenho na aplicação plugins como DataTables e Datepicker e ambos tem traduções que vem da pasta do Bower, mas como puxar dinamicamente usando minha variável PHP que muda o idioma no sistema?

Em muitos sistemas notei que tem váriaveis globais em JS que são colocadas no `head` com as traduções. Existe uma técnica para trabalhar com isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Em muitos sistemas notei que tem váriaveis globais em JS que são
>   colocadas no head com as traduções. Existe uma técnica para trabalhar
>   com isso?

Que fique claro: **isso aqui não é um tutorial**. Vc já deve ter noção do *framework*, e eu apenas vou exemplificar a passagem de uma variável da `$_SESSION` para o `JavaScript` usando as ferramentas nativas do *CodeIgniter*. Também não me preocupei muito com segurança, mas creio que não haja falha grosseira nesse código.

O objetivo é que vc perceba como atribuir os dados da sessão do `PHP` a uma variável `JavaScript`, o que, se entendi direito, responde à sua pergunta. Ou seja, vamos manipular o valor da variável `JavaScript` conforme ela for alterada no `PHP`.

Assim, use [sessions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session), [hooks](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html?highlight=hooks) e [helpers](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/index.html). O *hook* vai definir o valor de sessão padrão para a variável. O *helper* vai recuperar esse valor para o *JavaScript* e imprimir no documento `HTML`.

- **Habilitar o uso da biblioteca de sessão:**

Eu gosto de [autoload](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=loading#auto-loading-resources): entre em `application/config/autoload.php` e insira *session* no *array* correspondente: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session')`.

- **Definindo idiomas disponíveis:**

Esses dados podem, logicamente, ser carregados do seu banco. No exemplo eu definirei o `array $config['langs']` pra servir como referência. Entre em `application/config/config.php` e insira isso: `$config['langs'] = ['pt-br','en','es'];`.

Assim, essas serão as únicas hipóteses disponíveis para o método `set_lang_var()` que define o idioma.

- **Habilitar e criar um hook:**

Habilite o uso de *hooks* definindo `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;` no arquivo `application/config/config.php`;

Dentro de `application/config/hooks.php` insira o seguinte:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'function' => 'set_lang',
    'filename' => 'set_lang.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Agora crie o *hook* `application/hooks/set_lang.php` e insira o seguinte:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

function set_lang() {

    $ci = & get_instance();
    //$ci->session->unset_userdata('lang');
    if(NULL == $ci->session->userdata('lang')){
        //Se nao houver idioma na session, define o idioma padrao
        $userdata = ['lang'=>'pt-br'];
        $ci->session->set_userdata($userdata);
    }
    //Caso contrario, o metodo teste/set_lang_var() pode ser usado para mudar o idioma
}
```

A partir deste ponto o `PHP` já sabe qual é o idioma padrão. Agora será necessário fazer o sistema repassar os dados da `$_SESSION` do `PHP` para uma variável `JavaScript` legível.

- **Habilitando e criando um helper:**

Para usar os *helpers* vc deve carregá-los. Eu gosto de usar [autoload](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=loading#auto-loading-resources): dentro de `application/config/autoload.php` adicione o helper *string* ao *array* apropriado: `$autoload['helper'] = array('string')`;

É uma boa prática não alterar os scripts originais do *framework*, então  [estenda](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html?highlight=extending#extending-helpers) o *helper* pra poder trabalhar sem medo: crie o arquivo `application/helpers/MY_string_helper.php` e insira o seguinte:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (!function_exists('string_lang')) {
    function string_lang(){
        $ci = & get_instance();
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo "var lang='".$ci->session->lang."'";
        echo "</script>\n";
    }
}
```

- **Controlador, métodos e view:**

O *controller* `application/controllers/Teste.php` tem dois métodos bem simples:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Teste extends CI_Controller {

    function get_lang_var(){
        $data['title'] = 'get_lang_var()';
        $this->template_action = strtolower(__CLASS__."/".__FUNCTION__);
        $this->load->view($this->template_action, $data);
    }

    function set_lang_var(){
        $lang = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
        $userdata = ['lang'=>$lang];
        if(in_array($lang, $this->config->item('langs'))){
            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
            redirect('teste/get_lang_var');
        } 
        else{
             redirect('teste/set_lang_var/pt-br');
        }
    }

}
```

A *view* `application/views/teste/get_lang_var.php` também é bastante simples:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<?= doctype('html5'); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title><?= $title ?></title>
        <base href="<?= config_item('base_url') ?>">
        <?=string_lang()?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <style>body{padding-top: 20px;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Mude o idioma: <?=$_SESSION['lang']?></p>
            <?=anchor('teste/set_lang_var/pt-br', 'pt-br')?>
            <?=anchor('teste/set_lang_var/en', 'en')?>
            <?=anchor('teste/set_lang_var/es', 'es')?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Observando o console do navegador (ou o código-fonte da página) vai ser possível perceber que a variável `<script type="text/javascript">var lang='pt-br'</script>` muda de valor sempre que vc escolhe um idioma novo.

É isso. Estude este código e vc vai ter a noção de como fazer isso de outras maneiras, ou aplicar o conceito às bibliotecas que está usando.