# Como instanciar um objeto no Hooks para usar no Controller do CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

tenho uma classe que vai gerenciar algumas de minhas dependências. Quero que ela seja chamada antes de qualquer *method* ser chamado no *controller*, e para isso estou usando *hooks*. O problema é que eu não sei chamar esse objeto que já foi instanciado no *hook* nos meus métodos do *controller*. Como eu poderia fazer isso? Veja como está:

No *hook* eu estou usando esta configuração:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class' => 'DependencyInjection',
    'function' => 'initContainer',
    'filename' => 'DependencyInjection.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks');
```

E o arquivo `dependencia.php` está assim:

```
<?php
use Pimple\Container;

$container = new Container();

$container['guzz'] = function($c) {
    return new GuzzleHttp\Client();
};
```

O *hook* foi criado dessa forma:

```
<?php
class DependencyInjection {

    public $container;

    public function initContainer () {
        return $this->container = require_once '/var/www/projetoSize/dependencia.php';
    }
}
```

Eu quero usar isso no meu *controller* dessa forma:

```
class Teste extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        var_dump($this->guzz);
    }
}
```

Porém está dando erro com a seguinte mensagem:

> Message: Undefined property: Teste::$guzz

Comment: Vc está tentando carregar uma biblioteca, e não é essa a maneira correta de fazer. Leia [Creating Libraries](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=libraries#creating-libraries). Se a biblioteca for externa, [isso aqui](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/issues/122) tb pode ajudar.

Comment: Isso mesmo cara, você não faz ideia do quando me ajudou, muito obrigado cara ! eu tinha me esquecido disso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você precisa de uma classe que sirva métodos em todas as instâncias da aplicação, então deve usar uma biblioteca. No mínimo um *helper*. O *hook* é a própria extensão do *Core* do *CodeIgniter*, ou seja, ele é a classe propriamente dita, e vc não deve usá-lo pra carregar uma outra classe. Isso pode até funcionar, mas não é essa a função ideal da ferramenta.

**- Para usar um helper:**

Um *helper* é um script que contém uma coleção de funções pra ajudar a executar tarefas básicas. O *CodeIgniter* já tem uma série de funções dessas, e antes de tentar criar algo, talvez seja interessante verificar se o que vc quer já não está por lá. Procure na [coleção nativa de *helpers*](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/index.html).

Quando vc criar um *helper* e carregá-lo na aplicação, ele vai estar disponível em todas as instâncias:

> CodeIgniter does not load Helper Files by default, so the first step
>   in using a Helper is to load it. **Once loaded, it becomes globally
>   available in your controller and views**.

No entanto, um *helper* não vai receber requisições diretamente, no MVC sempre é a camada de controle que trata esse tipo de coisa. Então, vc deve chamar sua função *helper* dentro de um método de um *controller*.

Para entender como criar um *helper* e como ele funciona minimamente, leia o trecho "Habilitando e criando um helper" [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224661/como-traduzir-plugins-js-de-forma-din%C3%A2mica-com-codeigniter/228520#228520).

**- Para criar uma biblioteca:**

De acordo com as referências da [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=libraries#the-class-file), você pode criar uma classe e instanciá-la no *controller* que quiser usar:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Someclass {

        public function some_method(){

        }
}
```

Aí basta [carregar](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=libraries#using-your-class) a classe no *controller*:

```
$this->load->library('someclass');
```

Ou carregar com *[autoload](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=load)*:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = ['someclass'];
```

**- Carregando uma biblioteca de terceiros: ([referência](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/issues/122))**

Depois de baixar a biblioteca para um local no seu server declare que ela existe. Crie um arquivo dentro de *application/libraries/Classname.php*:

```
<?php
class Classname {
    function __construct() {
        require_once '/*path_to_classname.php*';
    }
}
```

Carregue com *autoload* e chame em qualquer lugar da aplicação (num *controller* ou num *helper*):

```
function some_function(){
    $func = new Classname();
    (...)
}
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui.